# How can we customize vs2010 css editor template?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ide

In particular, I do love to organize code blocks into regions by `#region` and `#endregion`. Is it possible to do something like this while editing css document?

Well, in general how can we customize vs2010 css editor template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the [JSEnhancements](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0696ad60-1c68-4b2a-9646-4b5f4f8f2e06) add-on for VS.NET it will let you use #region in css and js. For a list of js and css enhancements in vs.net please read [this](http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2011/05/improve-visual-studio-2010-jscript-editor-with-jquery-intellisense-and-code-outlining/).

Comment: A very nice add-on. Thank you so much.

Comment: One remark: can't make JSEnhancements' `//#region` work...`Collapse to definitions` works normally. But the *regions* feature does not. Must it be setup somehow?

Comment: It works for me in VS.NET 2012.. if you are using SASS or LESS to write CSS please check this great add-on http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench